# C program for sorting 3 random numbers , void reorder3(int a, int *b, int **c);

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, random

This code is working but its not exactly what I want. Is anyone have any idea how to make it correct and without q sort?. The idea is to understand how to use pointers.
The three numbers should be random between -3 and 12. The code below is something similar, and the closest I have found. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//functions
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
   const int *ia = a;
   const int *ib = b;

   if (*ia < *ib)
      return -1;
   else if (*ia > *ib)
      return +1;

   return 0;
}

//qsort function
void sort3(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
   int temp[3];

   temp[0] = *a;
   temp[1] = *b;
   temp[2] = *c;

   qsort(temp, 3, sizeof(int), &compare);

   *a = temp[0];
   *b = temp[1];
   *c = temp[2];
}

//random function
int rand_int(int a, int b)
{
return rand()%(b-a+1)+a;
}

int main(void)
{

   //declaration of variables
   int a,b,c;
   int rand_int(int a, int b);
   srand(time(0));  
   a = rand_int(-3,12);
   b = rand_int(-3,12);
   c = rand_int(-3,12);

   printf("%i %i %i\n", a, b, c);
   sort3(&a, &b, &c);
   printf("%i %i %i\n", a, b, c);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void sort3(int *a, int *b, int *c)` from the code and `void reorder3(int a, int *b, int **c)` from the title don't match together...

Answer (score 7):

You don't need the `compare()` function if you don't want to use `qsort()`.

You can rewrite `sort3()` like this:

```
void compare_and_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int t;
    if (*a > *b) {
        t = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = t;
    }
}

void sort3(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    compare_and_swap(a, b);
    compare_and_swap(a, c);
    compare_and_swap(b, c);
}
```

This is actually a "[bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)".

Comment: if you do `(a,c)` first you can call it shell sort :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of trouble to go for to sort 3 integers. Use if statements.

If the goal is actually to understand pointers, they seem intimidating but they're not so bad. Basically, they're a number that happens to be an address. You can manipulate like them numbers, but if you dereference them (with `*`), you can get the value there. This cuts both ways, though, because there's not much stopping you from dereferencing a value - which probably crashes your program (or more scarily, maybe not).

As long as you keep in mind what's an address and what's a value, you should be OK.

Comment: How do you dereference an `int`, for example? You only can deref pointers.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with pointers is that sometimes is seems very clear and sometimes I just don´t understand... I will try to keep that in mind !!

Comment: @glglgl - You just need to cast an int to a void*/other pointer type. I wouldn't recommend it in normal situations, but I did it just the other day to pass-by-value into a pthread (I know, but I had a race condition). You just need to be damn careful you know what's happening.

Comment: ok, then ITYM "there's not much stopping you from dereferencing a pointing storing an arbitrary value instead of an address". Then it becomes clear and I fully agree. But those things are to be done with extreme care and only under very special circumstances.